# How to convert ffmpeg command to Python code

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I would like to convert the command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.wav -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mp4` to a Python function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I achieve it on Linux.

```
def ffmpeg():
    cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "input.mp4", "-i",  "input.wav",  "-c:v", "copy",  "-map",  "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0",  "-c:a",  "aac",  "-b:a",  "192k",  "output.mp4"]
    
    ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    
    # wait until the process completes
    ffmpeg.communicate()
```

or if you need to see the output replace with

```
ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to write actual code instead of running the process?